# How to use pipe into grep to exclude list of files under a second level directory?

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, pipe, file-filter

I use ripgrep (rg) to list files under a directory.
But I want to list files under a second level directory excluding the list of files under one of the directories.

Basically if I have ./a/b/c
I want to list all files under a excluding files under b.
Something like:
rg --files ./a | grep -v (rg --files ./a/b)

I know the formula above is illegal but I want to achieve that in shell.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like:

```
find ./a -type f -not -path "./a/b/*"
```